# how to get stock item by Master ID

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, odoo, connector, tally

url1 = "http://localhost:9000"
xmlBody = "1EXPORTCOLLECTIONStockItems"
xmlBody += "$$SysName:XML"
xmlBody += "StockItemMaster ID"
req = requests.post(url = url1,data=xmlBody.encode('utf-8'))
res = req.text.strip().replace("&","and")
scrubbedXML = re.sub('&.+[0-9]+;', '', res)
print(scrubbedXML)
response = Et.fromstring(res)
url='https://dev1.mo.vc'
db='trainee5'
username='samiullah@xmedia.in'
password='samiullah'
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
for dat in response.findall('./BODY/DATA/COLLECTION/STOCKITEM'):
namei=dat.get('NAME')
print(namei)
number=dat.find('MASTERID').text
print(number)
print("Name:")
print(namei)
payload="""

1
EXPORT
OBJECT
stock item
**""" +namei+ """** i need  to retrive the stock item by Master ID (search)

```
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
    <DESC>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
    <FETCHLIST>
    <FETCH>OpeningValue</FETCH>
    <FETCH>OpeningRate</FETCH>
    <FETCH>OpeningBalance</FETCH>
    <FETCH>ClosingBalance</FETCH> 
    <FETCH>ClosingRate</FETCH> 
    <FETCH>Parent</FETCH>
    <FETCH>STANDARDPRICELIST.RATE</FETCH>
    </FETCHLIST>
    <TDL>
    <TDLMESSAGE>
    <OBJECT ID="stock item name" ISINITIALIZE="Yes">
    </OBJECT>
    </TDLMESSAGE>
    </TDL>  
    </DESC>
    </BODY>
    </ENVELOPE>"""  
    request=requests.post(url = url1, data=payload.encode('utf-8'))
    response = request.text.strip().replace("&amp;","and")
    scrubbedXML = re.sub('&.+[0-9]+;','' ,response)
    # print(scrubbedXML)
    try:
        respRoot = Et.fromstring(scrubbedXML)

    except:
        pass

    for data in respRoot.findall('./BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE/STOCKITEM'):
        try:
            name=data.get('NAME')
            # print(name)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            name='naa'
            pass
        try:
            closing_ba= data.find('CLOSINGBALANCE').text
            closing_bal=(re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', closing_ba))
            for s in closing_bal:
                closing_balance=float(s)
                # print(closing_balance)
        except:
            closing_balance=0
            pass

        parent=data.find('PARENT').text
        # print(parent)
        try:
            openbal=data.find('OPENINGBALANCE').text
            open_bal=(re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', openbal))
            for s_o in open_bal:
                opening_balance=float(s_o)
                # print(opening_balance)
        except:
            opening_balance=0
            pass
        try:
            openrate=data.find('OPENINGRATE').text
            open_rat=(re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', openrate))
            for s_or in open_rat:
                opening_rate=float(s_or)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below xml to get stock Item By masterID

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
    <ID>CustColl</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
             <!-- * Static variables like scfrom,svto,svexport format will not work -->
         
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CustColl">
                    <TYPE>masters</TYPE>
                    <!-- * will fetch all fields if you want specific fields you can specify -->
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>*</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    <FILTERS>filter</FILTERS>
                </COLLECTION>
                 <!-- You can  change filter to other than name also -->
                <!--to get any Master based on name  replace $Masterid with $Name  -->
                <!--Replace 1122 with Masterid you want to search -->
                <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="filter">$Masterid=1122</SYSTEM>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```

You can Get all xmls to communicate with tally [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13855108/TzeRpAMt#89be4e1a-345f-4e40-ae2e-d66afcc4bdfc)

I am trying to bring all tally xmls at one place

**Improvement:**

**If you are using c#/VB**

You can use [TallyConnector Library](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector)

Using Tally Connector API you can get StockItem in 4 lines of code

```
Using TallyConnector //Importing TallyConnector Library
Using TallyConnector.Models

public Tally Ctally = new Tally(); 
StockItem Item = await Ctally.GetStockItem(ItemName);
```

**If you are using Python**

You can [refer this guide](https://blog.saivineeth.com/en/TallyConnector/Python-Tally-Integration_Getting-Started/) on how to use [TallyConnector Library](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector) in python